# GPIO on Raspberry pi c#

Tags: c#, raspberry-pi, gpio

I'm currently working on a project to make a raspberry pi robot car thing using c#. I have absolutely no knowledge of c#, so this is my way of learning it.

The car uses an L298N to control the motors, so all I need to figure out how to get the pi to output high from one pin, and low from another, then I can work out how to control it.

But the point is, I wrote some code hoping that it would activate one of the motors, but it doesn't seem to. I was hoping someone who understands c# and GPIO pins better would be able to point out the errors.

Thanks, Callum

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices.WindowsRuntime;
using Windows.Foundation;
using Windows.Foundation.Collections;
using Windows.UI.Xaml;
using Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls;
using Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls.Primitives;
using Windows.UI.Xaml.Data;
using Windows.UI.Xaml.Input;
using Windows.UI.Xaml.Media;
using Windows.UI.Xaml.Navigation;
using Windows.Devices.Gpio;

// The Blank Page item template is documented at http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=402352&clcid=0x409

namespace App4
{
    /// <summary>
    /// An empty page that can be used on its own or navigated to within a Frame.
    /// </summary>
    public sealed partial class MainPage : Page
    {
        public void GPIO()
        {
            GpioController gpio = GpioController.GetDefault();
            if (gpio == null)
                return;
            using (GpioPin pin1 = gpio.OpenPin(5))
            {
                pin1.Write(GpioPinValue.High);
                pin1.SetDriveMode(GpioPinDriveMode.Output);
            }
            using (GpioPin pin2 = gpio.OpenPin(6))
            {
                pin2.Write(GpioPinValue.Low);
                pin2.SetDriveMode(GpioPinDriveMode.Output);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I don't have any knowledge of GPIO with C#, but you probably want to call `SetDriveMode` to output before you write to it, right?

Answer (score 0):

If you are not entirely sure the GPIO pin is the correct one, you can use this GPIO pin map: https://www.raspberrypi.org/documentation/usage/gpio-plus-and-raspi2/

As you can see GPIO pin 5 is at position 29.

If you're sure you have the correct pin, then I don't see much wrong with your code. The only problem I can think of is that you are using the using statement:

```
using (GpioPin pin1 = gpio.OpenPin(5))
{
    pin1.Write(GpioPinValue.High);
    pin1.SetDriveMode(GpioPinDriveMode.Output);
}
```

What this does is open the pin, write to it, and then immediately close the pin, which may result in the write not having completed before the pin is closed.

Unfortunately I cannot find anything in the docs https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.devices.gpio.gpiopin about whether or not the write process is executed immediately or not.

You can try to remove the using statement and call pin1.Dispose() manually later (when you are about to close the program for example)

in which case it would look like this:

```
GpioPin pin1 = gpio.OpenPin(5);
pin1.Write(GpioPinValue.High);
pin1.SetDriveMode(GpioPinDriveMode.Output);

...

pin1.Dispose();
```